# Trying to create a stacked bar

Tags: stacked-chart

Here are my codes:

```
a=df['Case Status'].value_counts()
a.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
```

**Results**

```
Closed      13
Notified     9
Name: Case Status, dtype: int64
```

[image]

I would like the bars to be stacked. May I know how do I achieve that?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Can you provide some context? What programmign language and/or plotting framework are you using?